# Is there a way to dynamically plot points taken from user without losing user's previous input points on the plot? (python)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

For example, if we have:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
ys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
name = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

while True:
    user_input = input('Enter name: ')
    for i, j, name in zip(xs, ys, name):
        if(user_input == name):
            ax.scatter(i, j)
            plt.show()
```

So basically here user enters a name and it gets plotted according to its xs and ys coordinates.

How can i make it so that if user enters the next name, it gets plotted too? without losing the previous name point on the plot? I am not sure if this is called "dynamic" plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with saving the previously selected names in a list, and then plotting each point, something like this:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
ys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

selected_names = []
while True:
    user_input = input('Enter name: ')
    if user_input == 'end':
        break
    
    selected_names.append(user_input)
    for i, j, name in zip(xs, ys, names):
        if name in selected_names:
            plt.scatter(i, j)
    plt.show()
```

Also note that you are changing the list "name" to be the last name in the list in your for loop, so i changed the name of the list of names to "names".

Ps. If you want the colors to be consistent, you will have to use a colormap of some sort, otherwise the color of "c" will change if you first plot "c" then plot "a" later.

Edit: If you really want stuff to be dynamic (plots that change instantly and smoothly with user input you can look into [IPyWidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: thats actually pretty smart and simple! thanks so much!